# My lines and ovals disappear when I resize or move scrollbars

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, graphics2d

i have a j Panel in a  jSrollbarPane in netbeans design mode. I want to paint permanently on it untill user presses the button "clear". My lines and ovals created in path() disappear when I resize or move scrollbars on UI.

My code segment is below, thank you in advance

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
//i create some public double arrays here like x[] and y[]
}

 private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      

        path(x, y, 0);
    }    
 public void path(double[] X, double[] Y, int type) {
        Graphics2D gfx = (Graphics2D) jPanel1.getGraphics();
        int xT, yT, xL, yL;
        getContentPane();
        scale = jSlider1.getValue();
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                gfx.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
                break;
            case 1:
                gfx.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                gfx.setPaint(Color.blue);
                break;
            case 2:
                gfx.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                gfx.setPaint(Color.green);
                break;
            case 3:
                gfx.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                gfx.setPaint(Color.red);
                break;
            default:
                gfx.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                gfx.setPaint(Color.yellow);
                break;
        }

        for (int l = 1; l < size; l++) {
            xT = (int) (scale * X[l - 1]);
            yT = (int) (scale * Y[l - 1]);
            xL = (int) (scale * X[l]);
            yL = (int) (scale * Y[l]);

            gfx.drawOval(xT, yT, 5, 5);
            gfx.drawLine(xT, yT, xL, yL);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

As soon as I saw your title, I knew that you were drawing using a Graphics object obtained via `Component#getGraphics()`. Don't do this.

You should not draw with a Graphics object obtained by calling `getGraphics()` on a component. This will return a Graphics object that is short lived, risking disappearing graphics or worse, a NullPointerException. Instead, draw in the JPanel's `paintComponent(...)` method either directly, or indirectly by drawing on a BufferedImage (yes, you can get its Graphics object via `getGraphics()`) and then drawing the BufferedImage to the GUI within the paintComponent method.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. So should I put the code of path() in paintComponent() ?  I know it's a noob question but can i pass parametres in it? BufferedImage looks difficult.. when should I use redraw();

Comment: @mehmet: You will need to create a class that extends JPanel and override its paintComponent method and do drawing in there. You will need to pass all drawing information into this JPanel class, usually changing fields, and then use those fields in the paintComponent method. For more detailed answer with code, consider creating and posting your [mcve] (please read the link). Also as a side recommendation, don't add MouseListeners to JButtons. Use ActionListeners instead.